# find number of solution for given equation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, roots

suppose we we have following equations and conditions
Let  $k$ be the number of real solutions of the equation
$e^x+x-2=0$  in the interval $[0, 1]$ and  and let  $n$ be the   number of real solutions that are not in $[0,1]$ Which of the following is true?

$k=0$  and $n=1$

$k=1$  and $n=0$

$n=k=1$

$k>1$

$n>1$

first of all what i have tried is  this:if we differentiate we get following  thing
$e^x=-1$
but how it is possible?,using wolfram alpha i got this result

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%2Bx-2%3D0

but how to prove it  using  mathematical procedure?have to i use newtons method  for compute actual root or there is some specific  theorem which helps me to determine it more easily?

Comment: Use derivative test to see if the function is increasing or decreasing. A strictly increasing/ decreasing function must be injective, so it can have at most one zero. Note that the function e^x + x - 2 takes both positive and negative values. Evaluate at 0 and 1. What can you conclude?

Comment: if we use derivative test we get that,$e^x+1>0$,so only solution is complex space right?because $e^x$ never equal to  $-1$

Comment: No, the derivative test shows that the function is monotonically increasing. You are not trying to find the extremum points in this question.

Comment: yes you are right and it is what i have said,for find extremum,we must set equal $e^x+1=0$  ,it is what  i have said in my previous comment,please  look at it

Comment: What I don't understand is why you are trying to find the extremum points of the function to locate its zeroes.

Comment: are there alternative ways?we have to find critical points right?

Comment: Certainly, if there is more than one zero, there is a critical point between them, so if you can show there are no critical points, then there can be at most one zero.

Comment: generally if we use  known theorem that  if at bound points function has different sign,then there is at least  zero between them,so  by we know that  in [0...1] there is at least some point where  our function is equal to zero,but what about real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I am moving my comment as an answer:

Use derivative test to see if the function is increasing or decreasing. A strictly increasing/ decreasing function must be injective, so it can have at most one zero. Note that the function $e^x + x - 2$ takes both positive and negative values by evaluating at 0 and 1. What can you conclude by the intermediate value theorem?

Also, you should not try to find extremum points to solve this question, for the zeroes of $e^x + x -2$ need not be extremum points.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the functions $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = 2 - x$. Now, the solutions for your equation in the interval $[0,1]$ are the points where $f$ and $g$ intersect. try graphing it!

Comment: they never intersect it on real number space

Comment: @dato please see the wolframalpha link above. It has only one solution.

Comment: @dato : I think you should plot them instead of saying they never intersect, because clearly you haven't. LJym89's suggestion is very clever and allows you to see immediately that there will be a unique zero. Using the mean value theorem you can show immediately that this zero will be between $0$ and $1$. And then you will be happy. The solution is real. =)

Comment: yes and it is not real solution right

Comment: @dato : No, it is a real solution.

Comment: i was confused about Lambert function,which was shown by wolframaplha

Comment: what about real solution outside of  [0..1 ]?there are infinity of them right?

Comment: How can it have infinitely many zeroes if you just concluded that the function is increasing from you observation $f'(x) = e^x + 1 > 0$, where $f(x) = e^x + x - 2$?

Comment: look please ,in my question there is such statment   and let n be the number of real solutions that are not in [0..1]

Comment: Dear @dato: You figured out the function is montonically increasing in $\mathbb{R}$. Then it must be injective in $\mathbb{R}$. This means that is can take a value at most once. You figured out there is one zero in the interval $[0,1]$. Combining these observations you get that this must be the only zero.

Comment: yes Dear @Rankeya,now i now answer of my question